# Datetime conversions to timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, salesforce, apex, soql

I'm trying to write some code that will filter records from SalesForce that have a value in a field that is not before now.  I have given up on trying to format a query that filters the results from SalesForce because not I have tried works and nothing anyone has suggested works (they all return "malformed request").  Although, I'm obviously open to suggestions on that front, too.

So, I have settled on something like this:

```
        now = datetime.now(pytz.UTC)
        disables = self.sssvc.query("select Name, Project__c, Ownerid, Id, DisableOn__c, User__c from PIXDisableUserTask__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending'")
        for disable in disables[u'records']:
            disable_on = disable[u'DisableOn__c']
            if disable_on < now:
                continue
            else:
                disables.pop(disable)
            print
        return disables
```

But when I'm done I end up with two incompatible date formats for comparison.  The problem is, I don't know how to convert the value of "now" from datetime and "disable_on" from SalesForce into time stamps that can be compared.  What I get is something like:

```
now = 2015-07-29 19:19:07.322224+00:00
disable_on = u'2015-06-24T12:00:00.000+0000'
```

I know I need to change disable from a string to an actual datetime object in UTC, but I don't know what formula to use.

Comment: Read the [`datetime` documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x ?

Comment: Try moment. Nice py lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Python 3.x** , you can use the following format -

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(u'2015-06-24T12:00:00.000+0000','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 12, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

You can also use the `dateutil.parser` method given below.

---

**For Python 2.x** , the `'%z'` directive is not implemented in Python 2.x (Atleast not in my Python 2.6) , but you can use [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) for parsing the date -

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(u'2015-06-24T12:00:00.000+0000')
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Note - You can use `dateutil` in Python 3 as well.

---

So for Python 2.x , your code would look like -

```
import dateutil.parser
now = datetime.now(pytz.UTC)
disables = self.sssvc.query("select Name, Project__c, Ownerid, Id, DisableOn__c, User__c from PIXDisableUserTask__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending'")
for disable in disables[u'records']:
    disable_on = dateutil.parser.parse(disable[u'DisableOn__c'])
    if disable_on < now:
        continue
    else:
        disables.pop(disable)
    print
return disables
```